# What is the correct way to terminate a running process when you exit the GUI in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

When I click the qbtn button to quit the GUI, the GUI goes away, but the process in `convert(filename)` continues running in the background.

How can I make it so that when a user presses the exit button, the GUI disappears and any running process terminates?

I am using pyqt5 GUI (below):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QFont, QColor, QIcon
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import threading, queue, time

file_queue = queue.Queue()

def get_logo_path():
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = Path(sys._MEIPASS).joinpath('files').absolute()
    except Exception:
        base_path = Path(".").absolute()

    logo_path = base_path.joinpath('pi_logo.png')

    return str(logo_path.absolute())

class WorkerThread(QtCore.QRunnable):

    __keep_alive = True

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue.Queue()


    def addJob(self,filepath):

        # Puts an item into the queue; if the queue is full, wait until a free slot is available before adding the item.
        self.queue.put(filepath)

    def run(self):
        while self.__keep_alive:

            # Remove and return an item from the queue. If queue is empty, wait until an item is available.
            convert(self.queue.get()) 

    def kill(self):
        self.__keep_alive = False

        # Calls the function that puts item into the queue
        self.addJob('')
        print("que: ", self.queue)

def convert(filename):

    #: main
    if filename == '':
        print("CONVERT() run when filename == ''")
        #return

    else:
        print("filename", filename)

        i2 = 1
        while i2 > 0 and i2 < 2500000:
            print("Hello, running process convert() (", str(i2), ")")
            i2 = i2 + 1



class TitleBar(QHBoxLayout):
    __layout = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap(get_logo_path())
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: #646464;}")
        self.addWidget(label)
        qbtn = QPushButton('X')
        qbtn.setFont(QFont("Arial", weight=QFont.Bold))
        qbtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: #641010; color: #FFFFFF;}")
        qbtn.setMaximumWidth(25)

        # Calls quit() when the ex button is clicked
        qbtn.clicked.connect(self.close_window)
        self.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.addWidget(qbtn)

    def close_window(self):
        print('DEF CLOSE_WINDOW(SELF): QUITTING GUI ONLY!!!!')
        app = QApplication.instance()
        for widget in app.topLevelWidgets():
            print("widget: ", widget)
            if isinstance(widget, QMainWindow):
                # Closes the window
                widget.close()

class BodyLayout(QHBoxLayout):
    __navigation = None
    __body = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        label = QLabel(
            'Drag and drop any directory into the window to begin conversion.'
        )
        label.setStyleSheet(
            "QLabel { background-color: #646464; color: #FFFFFF;}")
        label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.addWidget(label)

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    __layout = None
    __titlebar = None
    __body = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.__titlebar = TitleBar()
        self.__body = BodyLayout()

        self.__layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.__layout.addLayout(self.__titlebar, 1)
        self.__layout.addLayout(self.__body, 10)
        self.setLayout(self.__layout)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    __window = None
    oldPos = None
    oldY = None
    oldX = None
    workerThread = None
    threadPool = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.__window = MainWidget()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.__window)

        sizeObject = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(-1)

        self.setFixedSize(min(600, sizeObject.width()),
                          min(150, sizeObject.height()))

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow { background: #646464; }")

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.workerThread = WorkerThread()
        self.threadPool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
        self.threadPool.start(self.workerThread)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        for url in event.mimeData().urls():
            filepath = Path(url.toLocalFile())
            #if filepath.name.endswith('.xlsx'):
            if filepath.is_dir():
                self.workerThread.addJob(filepath)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

        if self.size().height() + self.pos().y() - self.oldPos.y() < 15:
            self.oldY = event.globalPos()
        else:
            self.oldY = None

        if self.size().width() + self.pos().x() - self.oldPos.x() < 15:
            self.oldX = event.globalPos()
        else:
            self.oldX = None

        if self.oldPos.y() - self.pos().y() > 60:
            self.oldPos = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = None
        self.oldY = None
        self.oldX = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.oldPos != None:
            delta = QtCore.QPoint(event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
            self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
            self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
        if self.oldY != None:
            delta = QtCore.QPoint(event.globalPos() - self.oldY)
            self.setFixedHeight(self.size().height() + delta.y())
            self.oldY = event.globalPos()
        if self.oldX != None:
            delta = QtCore.QPoint(event.globalPos() - self.oldX)
            self.setFixedWidth(self.size().width() + delta.x())
            self.oldX = event.globalPos()

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        print('DEF CLOSEEVENT() kills workerThread')
        self.workerThread.kill()
        #self.quit()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread continues because it will not be able to process the queue until `convert` returns from its while loop.

If you want to also be able to "kill" that, you'll have to constantly check the *quit* condition at each while loop.

A simple solution is to move the `convert` function directly within the `run()` function. *BUT*... note that the "killing" won't happen immediately, as some already scheduled process is still going to happen (in this case, the printing), and this is actually good, as there's no *nice* way to kill a process - and that's good for a moltitude of reason I won't explain here.

```
    def run(self):
        while self.__keep_alive:

            filename = self.queue.get()
            if filename == '':
                print("CONVERT() run when filename == ''")
                break
                #return

            else:
                print("filename", filename)

                i2 = 1
                while i2 > 0 and i2 < 2500000:
                    try:
                        # a non blocking get that constantly checks the queue
                        result = self.queue.get(False)
                        if result == '':
                            break
                    except:
                        pass
                    print("Hello, running process convert() (", str(i2), ")")
                    i2 = i2 + 1
                else:
                    continue
                break
```

Of course this is a very basic implementation, you might probably want to create some sort of *delayed queue* (that behaves as a request "buffer") for any other queueing that might happen while the conversion is in place, so that you can process it later, but that's not the scope of this question.